# MonoTouch File.ReadAllText throws exception on internal FileStream.Dispose()

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

The following code seems to occasionally produce this stacktrace. It looks like it is happening within the framework when the dispose method is called on the internal `FileStream` object? Seems like a bug to me, any ideas?

```
var previousVersion = long.Parse(File.ReadAllText(Paths.VersionFile));
```

StackTrace:

```
 System.IO.IOException: Invalid parameter
      at System.IO.FileStream.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.IO.Stream.Close () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.IO.StreamReader.Dispose (Boolean disposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.IO.TextReader.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at CatalystHD.Shared.BaseLoginController.CheckIfFirstRunThisVersion () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at CatalystHD.Shared.BaseLoginController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.get_View () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at CatalystHD.IPad.RootViewController.AnimateTo (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController aController, UIViewAnimationTransition transition) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at CatalystHD.IPad.RootViewController.Logout (Boolean timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at CatalystHD.IPad.NotebookSelectionController.logoutButton_Clicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonItem Callback.Call (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at CatalystHD.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

**EDIT**
`VersionFile` path is grabbed this way:

```
public static string VersionFile {
    get {
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        return Path.Combine(path, "version.dat");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is being passed in with `Paths.VersionFile`?

Comment: @DanielA.White See edits

Comment: We'll need more context about your application, e.g. I can run the code in a loop for 10000x without any issue, because something else must differ. Like when is that file created, updated, deleted ? by any different thread ? does it occurs on on devices, simulator, both ? ... and all version numbers.

Comment: Chris did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I think you might be running into a race condition due to the implicit `Flush()` that occurs during disposal of the under-the-hood `FileStream` in that `ReadAllText` call.

(caveat: not in front of mono sources, so can't confirm exact behavior)

Is it possible that:

- You are replacing/reopening/etc. the same file path in another thread?
- Deleting that path immediately after or in another thread?
- Otherwise losing access to the checked path? (file share unmounting?)